# How to use Order by in Informix-4GL Forms Screen

Tags: informix

I was able to successfully create forms n Informix-4GL based on the document I referred to ([Informix-4GL Reference Manual](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/epubs/pdf/ct1vbna.pdf)), but I'm struggling to find information on how to display things in order by asc within the forms.

I need some help pointing me in the right direction.

---

From a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77424750/how-to-use-order-by-in-informix-4gl-forms-screen?noredirect=1#comment136499875_77424750):

```
DATABASE store
SCREEN
{
    Teleid:[f000]
    Telephoneno:[f001]
    CustomerName:[f002 ]
}
TABLES customer
ATTRIBUTES
f000 = customer.Teleid;
f001 = customer.Telephoneno;
f002 = customer.CustomerName;
```

Each `telephoneno` will have multiple rows with different customer names and `teleids`. I want to Sort/Group the `teleid` rows in ascending order. I'm new to Informix 4GL forms and stuffs, so idk much ideas of arrays. All I want to achieve is that when I query `Telephoneno`, the form should display the rows based on teleid data in an ascending order.

Comment: There is not enough information here for us to be able to help you.  What does your form look like?  How is the sorted data to be displayed?  Are you displaying one record at a time on the screen but presenting the records in sorted order, or do you have an array on the screen and you want to ensure that the data in the array is in sorted order, or do you have some other display mechanism in place and a different theory of "in order".  Without at least some of that information, we can't help you.

Comment: DATABASE store
SCREEN
{
Teleid:[f000]
Telephoneno:[f001]
CustomerName:[f002 ]
}
TABLES customer
ATTRIBUTES
f000 = customer.Teleid;
f001 = customer.Telephoneno;
f002 = customer.CustomerName;

This is the form I prepared; each Telephoneno will have multiple rows with different customer names and teleids. i want to Sorting/Group the teleids row in ascending order and I'm new to Informix 4GL forms and stuffs, so idk much ideas of arrays. All I want for achieve when i query Telephoneno forms shoudl display rows based on teleid data n an ascending order.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You will have a query declared, probably using a scroll cursor so you can move backwards and forward through the list of rows.  That query simply needs `ORDER BY teleid` at the end to sort the data in increasing order.  There might be some trickiness to deal with if you need to edit the list of items, or add new rows, or remove old rows.  That depends on the overall application requirements.  But you can get quite a long way with a scroll cursor on an ordered data set.